# How to get visual studio debugger to completely ignore original source file location

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, nuget, visual-studio-debugging

I'm beginning the work of moving an internal class library (.net framework, C#) to a series of nuget .net standard packages, which we will also serve internally.  I'm in the research phase.

And I am attempting to research using the VS (2017) debugger and working to create our conventions for where debug versions of the packages (with symbols) will be and where the release versions (without symbols) will be.

I build a small dummy .net standard package in one solution, and have used nuget add to place it in a file share.  And I have successfully consumed it in a different solution.

However, when I try to step into the code in the consuming solution, somehow, visual studio is doing something smart and actually stepping me into the source at its ORIGINAL location.  Which is fine in some ways of thinking about it, but I want to simulate the situation of a different developer on a different machine consuming the package and not having that original source available, such that the only way to step into packaged code would be to consume a debug version with symbols.  But visual studio is foiling me by figuring out the original source location and I don't see how it is doing that.

How can I get VS to be "dumber" so I can simulate on my machine what it would be to consume packages on another machine that didn't have this package source?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I get VS to be "dumber" so I can simulate on my machine what it would be to consume packages on another machine that didn't have this package source?

You can try to **specify the Symbols of that .net standard project to exclude from automatic loading**.

**Detail:**

As we know:

> [The Program database (`.pdb`) files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/specify-symbol-dot-pdb-and-source-files-in-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2017), also called symbol files, map
>   identifiers and statements in your project's source code to
>   corresponding identifiers and instructions in compiled apps.
>
> Symbol files also show **the location of the source files**, and
>   optionally, the server to retrieve them from.

And the default setting of symbols loading for debugging in Visual Studio is that **Load all modules**:

[image]

That is the reason why Visual Studio smart and actually stepping your into the source at its ORIGINAL location.

So, to resolve this issue, we need to disable Visual Studio "Load all modules", we could specify excluded modules for your .net standard project.

To accomplish this, click the link on that window, then add the name of your .net standard:

[image]

Then Visual Studio get to be "dumber", not find the ORIGINAL location.

Hope this helps.